# image of $|z|= \pi\ $ under $ z \mapsto\ e^z\ $

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have been asked to sketch the image of $|z|= \pi\ $ under the mapping $ z \mapsto\ e^z\ $ ;

I think I should use the identity that $ z = |z| e^{i\theta}$ , and replace z in $ e^z $ with this identity; I'm not sure how to find $\theta$ though. I understand $ \theta = arg(z)$, but since I don't know z, what do I substitute for $\theta$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so $z = |z| e^{i\theta}=\pi e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ takes all possible values, that is all real numbers, $\theta\in(-\infty,\infty)$, though it would also be enough $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$

Comment: why is it that I can take all real values for $\theta$?

Comment: also, what would happen if I set $|z|< \pi$? taking all values of $\theta$ sounds like it'd take all values inside the circle of radius $\pi$ in the z plane, not just the boundary? 

Thanks a lot

Comment: since $|z|=\pi$ is a circle centered at the origin of radius $\pi$, and so is $\pi e^{i\theta}$. Use that $e^{i\theta}$ is the unit circle, when $\theta\in(-\infty,\infty)$. Use that $\theta$ only changes the angle, not the modulus, and since the modulus remains the same, $\pi$, you are describing the circle of radius $\pi$ (not its inside)

Comment: The whole point here is that the curve $|z|=\pi$ can be parametrized by $z = \pi e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta$ going from $0$ to $2\pi$. If you want to consider all points $|z| < \pi$ then you can do this by writing $z = r e^{i\theta}$ and consider this for all $0\leq r<\pi$ and all $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: $e^{\pi e^{i\theta}}=e^{\pi\cos(\theta)}(\cos(\pi\sin(\theta))+i \sin(\pi\sin(\theta)))$, using graphing software I get these graphs [whole graph](http://i.imgur.com/MJAy1LY.png) and a [detail](http://i.imgur.com/VDJVksK.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! are your axes actually Re(z) and Im(z) there?